# PrimeNg Menubar Custom Content not displayed

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I've followed the instructions in the docs in:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/menubar

In my module file i've imported the correct lib:

```
import {MenubarModule,MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

Then in my template I've defined:

```
<p-menubar [model]="items">
  <button pButton label="Logout" icon="fa-sign-out"></button>
</p-menubar>
```

However, the button is not rendered in html result. Have I messed somewhere?

Best Regards.

```
 imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpModule,
DataTableModule,
SharedModule,
ButtonModule,
MenubarModule,
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }, {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
])
```

],

Comment: Any errors from console?

Comment: No, nothing goes wrong in console.

Comment: Don't put "solved" in your title, just accept your own answer when the 48 hours is up.

Comment: Fine, Ill do it later on. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is refering to the 4.1 RC3 version, was using RC2 at the time:

https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=51618